# Developing classes and subclasses for hourly and salaried working

Tags: python

So, it is finals week at my school so I am practicing some extra problems in my textbook that our professor said "may or may not" be on the final that he has not taught yet. So I am stuck on the whole concept of classes. We are using Python. Here is the problem. Use these constructors: **int**()- constructor that takes as input the worker's nae (as a string) and the hourly pay rate (as a number), changeRate(): Takes he new pay rate as input and changes the worker's pay rate to the new hourly rate, pay()- takes the number of hours worked as input and prints 'Not Implemented'

Next develop classes HourlyWoker and SalariedWorker as subclasses of Worker. Each overloads the inherited method pay() to compare the weekly pay for the worker. Hourly workers are paid the hourly rate for the actual hours worked; any overtime hours above 40 are paid double. Salaried workers are paid for 40 hours regardless of the number of hours worked. Because the number os hours is irrelevant the method pay() for salaried workers should all be callable with an input argument.

So far I understand what I should input and what I should get after I have inputting it. But actually creating the function is not working at at.

So for my result I want to input

```
  w1 = Worker( 'Jeff', 15)
  w1.pay(35)
  Not Implemented
  w2 = SalariedWorker('Sam', 14.50)
  w2.pay()
  580.0
  w3 = HourlyWorker('Daisy', 20)
  w3.pay(25)
  500
```

If anyone could help me with this I would really appreciate the clarification. Oh and when I try putting a line like def **__*add*__**: into python it returns with a syntax error.

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed. You need to ask specific things. How to calculate a salary for hourly worker, how to inherit from classes in python, how to declare classes and methods inside them, how to override methods and so on

Comment: Also, don't just describe what you tried to write and how it failed; show us the actual code you wrote and the exception you got (with traceback). We can't tell you how to fix it if we can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following structures of classes shall attend what you need:

```
class Worker(object):
    payme = False
    period = None
    def __init__(self, name, sal):
        self.name = name
        self.sal = sal

    def pay(self, period=None):
        if not self.payme:
            print 'Not Implemented'
            return
        if self.period:
            return self.period*self.sal
        elif not period:
            print 'Please, give a period'
            return
        elif period:
            return period*self.sal

    def __add__(self, other):
        # here adding the salary (sal), but you can add whatever you wish...
        return self.sal + other.sal

class SalariedWorker( Worker ):
    payme = True
    period = 40

class HourlyWorker( Worker ):
    payme = True
```

Comment: It may be worth explaining what parts this doesn't handle. For example, `Worker.pay` is supposed to return `NotImplemented`, forcing `HourlyWorker` and `SalariedWorker` to override the method. (This is a silly way to do it in Python 2.7 or 3.x, but that's what the assignment asked for…)

Comment: that's true... now some better classes...

Comment: I was going to say that I think you're doing more work than the question as currently written warrants (and I can only +1 you once)… but really, it's probably just that you found it easier to explain in Python than in English, right?

Comment: yes.... as you probably guessed :D

Comment: That's the reason we all program in Python in the first place, so it's an easy guess. :)